# Will learning Java SE 5 now be relevant to SE 6, 7 and the up-coming 8?

Tags: java

I am wanting to learn Java, particularly for Android development since I am getting a new tablet but also for many of the other things Java can do (Struts, network development, JWebSockets, and others). I am a fairly experienced developer with PHP, Javascript and .NET, mostly (I would say I am about an intermediate coder).

My issue is that I prefer to learn from books since I feel they give a more all-inclusive learning experience than trying to patch together a whole bunch of tutorials. I also just enjoy reading technical books! However, I have found a book that looks good to me at a discount book store near me called "Learning Java, 3rd Ed." by Niemeyer and Knudsen. It looks like exactly what I am looking for since it doesn't seem to be a beginner book that spends 500+ pages explaining OO, variables and methods. But it is for Java SE 5!

So now there is a Java SE 6 version, SE 7 and I think there is even a beta of SE 8. How far behind would it put me to learn the Java class library (and generally how to program Java) of Java SE 5?

I found this question: [How difficult is it to learn Java SE 6 from J2SE 5.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657042/how-difficult-is-it-to-learn-java-se-6-from-j2se-5-0) but it seems that it was only referring to Java SE 5 vs. SE 6. But now there will soon be 2 more versions beyond that. I have also looked over feature lists of new versions, but without knowing the language better, I can't really tell how important the new versions are, or if they are mostly syntactic sugar. At the best, will I just need to maybe read some tutorials for upgrading developers, or at worst, would my SE 5 code break in SE 6, 7 or 8? Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, Java 7 was only [recently released](http://blogs.oracle.com/javase/entry/java_7_has_released), and I wouldn't expect Java 8 to be released anytime soon.

From a Java versions perspective, the release from Java 1.4 to Java 5 was the biggest change, in my opinion - enough that Sun started referring to Java 1.5 as "Java 5". This was the version that introduced new core features such as Generics, Annotations, etc. The jump from Java 5 onward won't be as big of a change compared to the earlier revisions, in comparison; mostly Java 6 & 7 add to the standard libraries, as well as some new syntactic sugar such as try-with-resources.

Either way, I'd say go for the book. Java 5 is a good start, and once you understand the language you can move on to the new features that Java 6 & 7 provide, such as java.util.concurrency, nio, blah, blah, blah...

Comment: Ahh, maybe I was jumping the gun a bit about SE 8. Now that I look at it, it looks like it is just a recommendation being put together, which would mean it is still far off.

Comment: Now several years later it turned out that Java 8 has as much new, as Java 5 did.  Java 5 knowledge is still important and useful though.

Comment: Definitely! I don't know if I'd now recommend buying a Java 5 book in 2016 though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Java 6 has some significant library improvements over Java 5 but few changes to syntax outside some improvements to the way annotations are done, so it won't be hard to pick up 6 incrementally.

Java 7 and (likely) 8 are much bigger changes, but you'd probably be learning them at the same time as the rest of the Java community.  Java 7 is still early in the adoption cycle.

Comment: Java 7 has some much bigger changes? All the interesting things planned for Java7 were pushed back to 8 in my opinion :( (modules, lambda mostly). Is there anything apart from the diamond operator and string switches I'm forgetting? Both are "nice" but trivial to learn and not much of a time saver.

Comment: @Voo, For example, `java.nio.file` includes a complete rewrite of the way file system interaction is done including file system eventing.  That's not an incremental library change that builds on old knowledge.

Comment: Sure but that's still a library addition to me since you could write an async IO framework in Java5 just as well (at least I think you could?). If we're talking about library improvements there's no doubt at all that Java6 was a big step forward - eg the concurrent collections got some nice overhaul as well. But I think language feature-wise we've been pretty stagnant since Java5.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Oracle would do anything that would break Java 5 code in later versions of Java, provided that you didn't use any proprietary or deprecated API's.

With respect to Android, it has its own set of libraries which are not completely the same as any particular version of Java offered by Oracle. 
Learning Java 5, and then going through the Android tutorials, and finally looking up the API when you need it should be sufficient for Android.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between Java5 and Java6/7 language wise are minimal. There's some new syntactical sugar (let's see: Diamond operator, string switch,.. can't think of anything else) in Java7 but that's about it.

Java5 already includes the most important changes to Java in a long time: Generics and enums.

The only thing that was really improved with Java6/7 (6 especially) is library support: There are lots of classes in the JDK you won't find in Java5, but that shouldn't worry you too much when learning the language.